# STL structures: "insert if not present" operation?

Tags: c++, optimization, data-structures, stl, unordered-map

I'm working on a program right now dealing with some exponential time algorithms. Because of this, a main loop of my program is being run many times, and I'm trying to optimize it as much as possible.

Profiling shows that a large portion of the time is spent in look-up and hash calculation for `std::unordered_map`.

I'm wondering:

1. Is there a way to cache the hash value of a key for `std::unordered_map`, and then provide it as an argument to insert later on?
2. Is there a way that I can do the following in a single operation: given an key and value `{x,y}`, check if key `x` is in the map, if it isn't, insert it and return `{x,y}`, otherwise return `{x,z}` for whatever `z` is already in the map.

I'm doing something like this right now, but it's inefficient, because I have to calculate the hash for the key and check if it's in the map. But if it isn't in the map, I do a completely separate insert operation. In theory, checking if it is present in the map should find where it would go in the map if inserted.

I'm open to trying other data structures, like `std::map` or something from Boost, if they would reduce the time for this operation.

Comment: Use threads instead. Or you could parallelize your loop using OpenMP

Comment: What's the key type?

Comment: You might even want to give a `std::vector` a go as it very cache and prefetcher friendly.  see: http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/11/cpp-benchmark-vector-vs-list.html

Comment: Btw, have you looked into insert hints?

Comment: @SergeyA, I have not, I hadn't heard of those. There's a couple of key types, one is `uint32_t`, the other is a struct which is just a pair of 32-bit ints, but I needed to use a struct to make a custom hash for them.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I'm dealing with very large (exponentially large) data, so the O(n) lookup for vectors would likely kill me, and I'm probably too large to be getting too much benefit from the cache anyways.

Comment: There is a form of insert function which accepts a hint - an iterator pointing to where the search would start from. If you already have a position, you can try this. This would be mostly useful for ordered maps, though.

Comment: @NathanOliver, what does vector vs list comparison  have do with associative containers????

Comment: @PoojaNilangekar I'll look into that, but 1. paralellizing is a completely separate issue from reducing data structure access 2. It's non-trivial to paralellize an algorithm (with dependencies on previous iterations) and 3. If I'm already having overhead from data structure accesses, the overhead from using a thread-safe data-structure would be even worse.

Comment: Can I assume that the answer to question 2 makes question 1 obsolete? You'll only need to calculate the hash once per object in that case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use the return value of [`std::unordered_map::insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) to achieve key existence checking + insertion with single hash calculation.

```
template<typename K, typename V>
std::pair<K, V> myinsert(std::unordered_map<K, V> &map, const std::pair<K, V> &kv)
{
    return *(map.insert(kv).first);
}
```

Comment: Side note: There is also std::map::emplace

Comment: It should be enough to return `V` by itself, since the key is already known - it was passed into the function.

Comment: @DieterLücking I'm suggesting changing the return value, not the parameters. `return (map.insert(kv).first)->second`.

Comment: Does this write over the value `v` previously associated with `k` with whatever is in `kv.second`?

Comment: No. According to document, the existing kv pair is returned and kept as-is.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use [std::map::emplace()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace).

The insertion only takes place **if no other element in the container has a key equivalent to the one being emplaced** (keys in a map container are unique).

Example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <map>

typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> StringMap; 
typedef std::pair<StringMap::iterator, bool> PairKey;

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> m;

    // uses pair's template constructor
    m.emplace("a", "aaa");
    m.emplace("b", "bbb");
    m.emplace("d", "ddd");

    PairKey pair = m.emplace("d", "dddddd");

    if (pair.second == false)
        std::cout<< "d was existed so value didn't change" << std::endl;
    
    std::cout<<"-------MAP_LIST------" << std::endl;
    for (const auto &p : m)
       std::cout << p.first << " => " << p.second << '\n';
    std::cout<<"-------========------" << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
d was existed so value didn't change
-------MAP_LIST------
a => aaa
b => bbb
d => ddd
-------========------
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't cache the hash of the key, but if you have an iterator to where it was last time (either from when you originally inserted, or the last time you successfully found the item) you can use the `insert( const_iterator hint, value_type&& value );` member which also helpfully returns an iterator to either the newly inserted element or the previously existing element that blocked insertion.

Comment: What do you mean by "where it was the last time"? As in, the iterator from the last time I did insert, or the iterator from when I did `find(x)` and it didn't find it?